# The getter 'length' was called on null exception in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, exception

I compiled my code, and received this error. My contacts are not empty (as you can see in the image) still it is giving me an error on being called as null.

One important point too. As you can see in my UI, the length or count of my contacts, i.e. 3 is being displayed, despite of the exception, and the word "contact" is not being displayed. Can someone explain me this too?? (Refer to line 38 of code, i wrote the word "contact" after the "count/length of contacts").

The UI -

[image: The UI of given Code]

Here is the code -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_whatsapp/Widgets/new_contact_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter_whatsapp/Widgets/specific_card.dart';

class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactsPageState createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage> {

  Iterable<Contact> _contacts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getContacts();
  }

  Future<void> getContacts() async {
    final Iterable<Contact> contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
    setState(() {
      _contacts=contacts;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Select contact'),
            Text(
              _contacts.isNotEmpty ? '${_contacts.length} contacts' : 'No Contacts yet',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10.0,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
            ),
            onPressed: (){},
          ),
          PopupMenuButton<String>(onSelected: (value) {
            print(value);
          }, itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return [
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text("Invite a friend"),
                value: "Invite a friend",
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text("Contacts"),
                value: "Contacts",
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text("Refresh"),
                value: "Refresh",
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text("Help"),
                value: "Help",
              ),
            ];
          }),
        ],
      ),
      body: _contacts != null
          ? ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _contacts.length ?? 0,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          Contact contact = _contacts?.elementAt(index);
          if (index == 0 ) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                SpecificCard(
                  iconData: Icons.group,
                  name: "New Group",
                ),
                SpecificCard(
                  iconData: Icons.person_add,
                  name: "New Contact",
                ),
                NewContactCard(uint8list: contact.avatar, text: contact.initials(), color: Theme.of(context).accentColor, name: contact.displayName),
              ],
            );
          }
          return NewContactCard(uint8list: contact.avatar, text: contact.initials(), color: Theme.of(context).accentColor, name: contact.displayName);
        },
      ) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the error/exception -

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building ContactsPage(dirty, state: _ContactsPageState#c06d4):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ContactsPage file:///C:/Users/Hp/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_whatsapp/lib/Pages/chat_page.dart:74:75
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _ContactsPageState.build (package:flutter_whatsapp/Pages/contacts_page.dart:38:28)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4612:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4495:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
...
====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

`_contacts` is loaded/initialized in `async` manner and simply speaking it is not initialized right away when the first time UI is beeing drawn/initialized.

To fix it, simply preset it with an empty list.

```
Iterable<Contact> _contacts=new List<Contact>();
```

It is always a good idea to initialize state fields with non-null values (unless null is specifyiong the some state)

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked, but instead of using - new List<Contact>(); (as it is depreciated in new version of flutter) we should simply use a list literal, i.e. [ ], and everything was working fine.

Comment: Allright then - I am not aligned with flutter. In both cases effect is the same - no null reference. Im glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a FutureBuilder to call `getContacts()`